# Bot Framework asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, botframework

As we all know that Asp.net WEB API is not a good option to use when working with front end of a web application. And Bot Framework template is based on WEB API I'm developing a bot but I want to use mvc or .net core instead of web api.

can we do so ?
if yes what changes I have to make for that in other templates LIKE MVC or .NET Core?

Comment: Why not just create a separate controller that extends `Controller` instead of `APIController`? You can have both in one project.

Comment: It's unclear if the question is about ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core as it contains both tags.

Comment: Actually I'm developing an application where I don't want to create by bot in a separate project (web api) and consume its services in different project (asp.net mvc or core) which will be directly access by user. so I want to create all in one application where I can manage my bot logic as well as a my other business logic

Answer (score 0):

Your question a little bit confusing.

ASP .NET Web API based on MVC. The connector client already support .NET Standard as far I know. .NET Core port is in progress but [here](https://github.com/CXuesong/BotBuilder.Standard) is basic port from the main repo. Most of the stuff inside the bot builder uses simple API because, this a connector to your 3rd parties ( slack , skype etc ).

Comment: Actually I'm developing an application where I don't want to create by bot in a separate project (web api) and consume its services in different project (asp.net mvc or core) which will be directly access by user. 

so I want to create all in one application where I can manage my bot logic as well as a my other business logic.

Comment: As far as I know there no pre-existing template for your needs but you can easily create those. You already have reference to MVC so you plug in your normal MVC flow. You can create a mvc app copy & paste the assets ( views , js , css ) and plug-in the configuration part. If you want to make it easy to your company to create new applications, in .NET Core you have to chance to create new templates ( http://rehansaeed.com/custom-project-templates-using-dotnet-new/ ) .